Can I use higher frequency rated ECC RDIMMs on platform that supports only lower frequency?
I have a 1st gen EPYC 7XX1 platform that supports only up to 2666MHz freq ECC RDIMMS. I would like to add more ram to this platform and I was thinking about purchasing 3200MHz modules for future proofing. I'm planning on using those 3200MHz modules later on a newer EPYC system that supports that 3200 frequency.
Can I generally speaking use higher frequency RDIMMS on older platform that supports only lower frequency memory modules? Does the system negotiate the frequency backwards with the module and is this standard behavior?
